# BigQuery convert arrays of key:val items to table of rows where the columns are the keys

Tags: google-bigquery

Say I have this arrays in bigquery (the result of splitting a string)

```
["user_id: 1342", "foo: bar", "baz: xxx"]
["user_id: 4312", "foo: ds", "baz: dss"]
["user_id: 512", "foo: fsf", "baz: aas"]
....
```

I wonder if there is an option get result as a table that looks like this:

| user_id | foo | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1342 | bar | xxx |
| 4312 | ds | dss |
| 512 | fsf | aas |
| ... | ... | ... |

What I'm trying to do is to parse logs message that have this structure:
`some log text... user_id: 123, foo: bar, baz: xxx`

I already parsed the string to have the initial arrays by using SUBSTR, STRPOS and SPLIT, but I can't figure how to move the keys to the column and have the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) query.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT ["user_id: 1342", "foo: bar", "baz: xxx"] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT ["user_id: 4312", "foo: ds", "baz: dss"] UNION ALL
  SELECT ["user_id: 512", "foo: fsf", "baz: aas"]
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn) FROM (
  SELECT SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] k,
         TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)]) v,
         rn
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn FROM sample_table), UNNEST(arr) kv
) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(v) FOR k IN ('user_id', 'foo', 'baz'));
```

Comment: Thanks! indeed pivot is the way to go